# How to increase the value of the number in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a beginner. Just started to learn JavaScript. Would like to find out how to simply increase the value of the number in array?
For example, I have the array with numbers inside:

```
var myArray = [2,3,5,10];
```

I would like to add 2 to item[1] so the myArray could look as below:

```
myArray = [2,5,5,10];
```

Comment: Isn't this in every beginners tutorial somewhere just after the chapter "Hello world"? Normally I would advise you to stay away from this, but they actually improved: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: Perhaps read the second chapter of the book

Comment: Please do some of the work for your self before posting on SO.

Comment: We were all beginners once. And it's not like we had to research for hours to help this person out.

Comment: Yeah, but when we started out we didn't have things like MDN, w3schools, the internet to help us. We just did our own research. The OP has __all__ these resources but can't lift a finger to help themselves out. It's really sad.

Answer (score 2):

```
item[1] += 2;
```

Not too different from most languages.

Comment: It's `myArray[1] += 2;` tho.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to using "+= 2"

```
myArray[1] += 2;
```

or

```
myArray[1] = myArray[1] + 2
```